# I can't get some external jquery to work

Tags: jquery, external

I hate to ask simple questions like these but I've been working at this for a couple hours now.

I've checked for all the common mistakes: I'm using .ready(), the code call is after the jquery library has been loaded and I'm sure the chrome console is working with the "All" option enabled.

Here's my code, eventually I'll be using ajax, but for now I just need to get the jquery to send the message to the console:

HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="../libraries/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/validardatos.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/registro.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../libraries/ajaxcall.js"></script> <!-- THIS IS THE REBELLIOUS DOC-->
</head>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

Comment: Are you sure jquery is getting loaded by the client?

Comment: Erm, if that's your whole `head` section, them maybe you forgot to include the script which actually contains your code?

Comment: I don't think so, ajaxcall.js is the document which has the jQuery code. The jQuery code I posted is the whole document, from head to toe, am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if you remove everything other than jquery and the offending script? What happens if you move the offending script onto the page in a script block? Any other console errors? Have you made sure all your resources have benn downloaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you can add jquery to your site by getting it from google's cdn
that will add jquery to your site without loading it from your server
add this to your site in the head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

hope this helps

P.S. you could also add all your code from ajaxcall.js to your site